# Mysterious vibrations from "System Interface"

Tags: notifications, system-apps, vibration, android-10

For some time my Samsung Galaxy Note 9 vibrates for no apparent reason. It's a very short vibration with no notification of any kind so at first I thought I'm imagining things. But I noticed it's really there so I tried to find out which app is to be blamed - using [Nice Catch](https://galaxystore.samsung.com/detail/com.samsung.android.app.goodcatch) I got a *Vibration history* for my phone (please excuse polish language on the screenshots):

[image: Vibration history]

Here comes the issue: these irregular vibrations come from **Interf. sys.** which I presume stands for System Interface. But as you can imagine googling "Android System Interface" wasn't very successful. Logo is just an Android Q logo so that doesn't help either.

I found this app among system applications, but it's *Notifications* settings are all locked (except for *Screenshots* and *App icon notifications*):

[image: Interf. sys. notifications]

So now I'm kinda stuck and have no idea how to proceed. Any ideas on what I can do to disable those irritating vibrations?

Comment: Does this happen only when you are using the phone (screen on) or while not using the phone?

Comment: @Puspam screen off only.

Comment: It's System UI app (package name `com.android.systemui`) which is the core platform app to manage user interface including lock screen, wallpaper, status bar and notification panel.

Comment: This sounds like an OS corruption issue. You might need to try a factory reset, sadly.